# JavaScript: toLocaleTimeString() is different in Explorer And Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, explorer

I found something strange in Explorer 11.
Here is the code:

```
var d = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { minute: "numeric"});
console.log(d);
```

Explorer 11 console: ‎6‎/‎14‎/‎2016‎ ‎2‎:‎27‎:‎15‎ ‎PM

Chrome console: 27

How can I get only the current minute with toLocalTimestring function in Explorer 11?

https://jsfiddle.net/34jd1zap/

Comment: toLocaleTimeString() doesn't take arguments. You use a mozilla extension.

Comment: I think what @Holger is refering to is [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString) which also includes a list of browsers which understand this syntax. Safari wouldn't which would make this approach of getting the minutes a no-go for me.

Answer (score 3):

What about .getMinutes() method? =)

```
var minutes = (new Date()).getMinutes();
```

Comment: Since minute formatting is not locale specific (as far as I know) this is probably the best way.